# Is there a setting in Opera to allow tabbing through links as well as form fields?

Tags: keyboard, browser, opera

In some browsers, the tab key moves the browser’s focus through form fields *and* links on the current web page.

In Opera (on the Mac, version 10.10), it only seems to move the focus through form fields, not links.

Is there a setting (or keyboard shortcut) to get the tab key to focus links as well as form fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Opera 10.50 for Windows, I notice that <kbd>Tab</kbd> does actually switch between fields and links (at least the ones linked to the form). So maybe it's linked indeed to your version and OS.

Besides, in Opera, you can also navigate between all links and fields by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + arrows. Maybe this can be a workaround.

Comment: Aha, shift and arrows — I had a feeling Opera had some sort of alternative keyboard navigation thing going on. Excellent, many thanks.